# Add White Layer on top of Main Window

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add a white layer on top of a Main form when a modal window appears on top of it so that it gives prominent to the modal window and kind of make the background transparent.
Add 75% Opaque white background for example...

Can it be done in Win forms?

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you cannot make it *more* white.  You can only make the background *less* white.  Covered by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20046160/17034).

Comment: Yes.. If I follow the solution in this post, It creates a white form but I need to put it in between the Main Form and modal window, currently it shows up on top of modal window. If I bring the modal window to front, its not visible, it becomes visible only after I close the modal window..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this might be to disable the main container control in your main form.  That usually gives a faded look to everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parent form enabled property to false after you open the child form, which will make the parent form read only and darker, so it's obvious the parent form is not active.

```
form1.Enabed = false;
```