# How to display windows 8 metro.style modal bar messages in Winforms?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, winforms, windows-8.1

I am talking about these:

[the message bar http://is.gd/j5iwbC](http://is.gd/j5iwbC)

I'd like to show one like this from my application. Also I'd like to customize it (this is a yes/no but I'd like to have one with one button, or even one without)

Maybe it can be doable with some sort of WPF integration (if this is made available to it).

Comment: You can't get that on the regular desktop.  But is very easy [to simulate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20046160/17034).

Comment: Windows itself shows it even on desktop with the "battery is low" message, for example.

Comment: True.  Rephrase that to "You can't get that from a regular desktop app".

Comment: I'll go for the simulation, then (unless somebody taps into windows internals).

Comment: @HansPassant how does one call that window from an App?